# Convert image file to base64 string in chunks Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, base64

I have an objective-c project with an image file that I want to convert to base64 string, i don't want to convert it first to NSData and then use `base64EncodedStringWithOptions`, I want to read the file chunk by chunk. So I create this method:

```
-(NSString*) base64EncodeFileAtPath:(NSURL*)url with:(NSUInteger)chunkSize {
    NSMutableString *base64EncodedString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    NSString * t = [url.absoluteString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"encrypted-file://" withString:@""];

    NSInputStream *inputStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithFileAtPath:t];
    if (!inputStream) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to create input stream from file");
        return nil;
    }

    [inputStream open];

    @try {
        uint8_t *buffer = (uint8_t *)malloc(sizeof(uint8_t) * chunkSize);
        
        while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
            @autoreleasepool {
                NSInteger bytesRead = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:chunkSize];
                if (bytesRead < 0) {
                    NSError *readError = [inputStream streamError];
                    if (readError) {
                        NSLog(@"Stream read error: %@", readError);
                    }
                    break;
                }
                
                NSData *dataBuffer = [NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:bytesRead];
                
                NSString *base64Chunk = [dataBuffer base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
                [base64EncodedString appendString:base64Chunk];
            }
        }
        
        free(buffer);
    }
    @finally {
        [inputStream close];
    }

    return base64EncodedString;
}
```

This is how i call the method:

```
[self base64EncodeFileAtPath:fileURL with:10 * 3600];
```

The problem is that when I want to decode the file back to the image I get an empty image, so I think that the encoding is broken, because when I use:

```
NSData* data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];
NSString * value = [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

everything is ok, any idea what can be the problem?

EDIT

---

The fileUrl is linked to a file that was encrypted and maybe this is the problem

Comment: If you compare `value` & `base64EncodedString`, how much do they differ? Try by outputting only the n first characters, and go one?

Comment: @Larme good idea! there is a difference between the two, the new function is 76568 size and the base64EncodedStringWithOptions is 76544. Any idea what can cause it?

Comment: How do you decode? As with base64 encoding, there could be new lines inserted (depending on the size), padding, etc. If you compare the content, piece by piece, where does it start to differ?

Answer (score 0):

What is chunkSize? Base64 increases original size at 4/3 rounded up. So if yours chunkSize is not divided at 3, result will have dummy characters. To avoid dummy characters in the result you should use chunkSize dividable to 3.